# approximate coordinates in a one dimensional lattice

Tags: nt.number-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, algorithms, lattices

suppose I have a finite set of real numbers ${r_1, \ldots r_n \in \mathbf{R} }$ and a single real number $x \in \mathbf{R}$. Is there a fast algorithm for finding integer numbers ${i_1, \ldots i_n \in \mathbf{Z}}$ such that

$
  \left| i_1 r_1 + \ldots + i_n r_n - x \right| < \epsilon
$

For a given $\epsilon > 0$ ? I know  that $i_1 r_1 + \ldots + i_n r_n = 0$ iff $i_j = 0 \,\forall j$.

Comment: What kind of real numbers are you talking about? If you mean rationals, then you could multiply by the common denominator then apply [Bézout's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_diophantine_equation#B.C3.A9zout.27s_identity_for_several_integers). On the other hand, *general* real numbers are inherently hard to handle in algorithms. If you have floating point numbers in some computer in mind, then you should make that explicit as well.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to say that I have floating point numbers.

Comment: $n=2$ is sufficient to do this.

Comment: i707107: That's clearly not always true if there are irrational numbers involved. eg it's not true if $ x $ is rational and the ratio of $ r _{1} $ to $ r _{2} $ is irrational.

Comment: Floating point numbers are inherently rational, but it becomes important to ask if the answers are constrained by what can be represented (eg number of digits), or if approximate answers are acceptable to some level of accuracy.

Comment: @mc0e: When $n=2$,if $1$ and $r_2/r_1$ are linearly independent over rational numbers(which is true because of OP's assumption), then $\mathbb{Z}+(r_2/r_1)\mathbb{Z}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$.